# Date format is reversing in uat releases

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, sts

```
    else if (type == Types.DATE) {
        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        short newDateFormat = createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(newDateFormat);
        cellx.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        cellx.setCellValue(result.getDate(i + 1));  
        System.out.println("This is date:"+result.getDate(i + 1)); 
     }
```

So I'am printing data from oracle database using spring frameworks into excel by using apache-poi with java v1.7 and tomcat server v8.5
I want to print date in dd-MM-yyy format in excel which i've achieved in my localhost using sts ide
But in uat release the date format is reversing to yyyy-MM-dd format which is incorrect according to my requirement.

Ps. My uat server is using java 1.6 and weblogic.

Comment: Isn’t that a setting in Excel?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what the problem is. In the first paragraph you state that the problem is with Excel but in the second paragraph you state that in Excel it is correct and the error is with `System.out.println` in Java; which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Writing dates into an excel via POI may occasionally result in lot of date format related problems.
The reason is LOCALE differences. In UAT, the machine might be running on a different time zone and country resulting in different date formats.
I am assuming it's not a mandatory requirement that you store the date in 'Date' type cell in the excel.
If yes, then you should first set the cell format type as 'String' format, then store the date as a TEXT instead of a DATE.
This will ensure that the LOCALE setting will not impact the date since you are storing a TEXT.
...

```
else if (type == Types.DATE) {
                        CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
                        //short newDateFormat = //createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        cellStyle.setDataFormat(STRING TYPE);//set string format here
                        cellx.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                            cellx.setCellValue(result.getDate(i + 1)); //CONVERT IT INTO  STRING FIRST, THEN STORE 
                            System.out.println("This is date:"+result.getDate(i + 1)); 
                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments over your code snippet:

```
short newDateFormat = createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // Create new date format
cellStyle.setDataFormat(newDateFormat); // Set the date format on the cell style
cellx.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
cellx.setCellValue(result.getDate(i + 1));  
System.out.println("This is date:"+result.getDate(i + 1)); // print result.getDate(i + 1) which apparently is some date
```

So my point is you are setting formatter on the cell but your date (result.getDate(i + 1)) is something different. If you use it on a second place you have to format it also there. You can try to reuse the same formatter if possible. You can also format it one place from date to string object and then use this string object on the places where you need